# Using trash program with sshfs possible?

Tags: sshfs, trash

When using `trash` of the package trash-cli in a mounted sshfs it does not put it to trash but gives me `trash: cannot trash regular file 'ex.e495213.1'`.

Is there a way to use a trash program in a mounted sshfs (or possibly there is a better FUSE all along)?

Comment: Does `trash` have the ability to write to the root of the `shhfs` mount?

Comment: No it does not. Is this the problem? Can there be a workaround then?